# Active and passive voice

Tags: grammar, british-english, verb-agreement, passive-voice, active-voice

Which of the following statements is correct?

1. It is I who am to be blamed.
2. It is I who am to blame.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be about active/passive voice.

Comment: The normal rule doesn't apply because [to blame](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/to-blame) is a set expression.

Comment: @Kate Bunting:  Yes, but it is a bit more, surely that just that.  There are other related structures, such as "The lady is not for burning", where we might say she is 'to be burned'.  And we do say both "the bonfire is ready to light" and "the bonfire is ready to be lit".  I think I had better have a look at my Oxford English Dictionary.  Could it be, for example, as simple as that the copula is in such cases 'easy to omit' without altering the meaning - what else, after all, could it mean?

Comment: They are both correct. The first is passive voice, the second is active. The somewhat special infinitival "to blame" is complement of "be"